# How to not Hard code the program in java? Used property file. But unable to use it with multiple xpaths?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Scenario: Download a new month report from the site.

Month.txt: Oct(2015) Unconventional wells

Here is the structure:

config.properties:

```
#browser
browser=http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOil_Gas%2fOil_Gas_Well_Historical_Production_Report
#drop-down box
list_box= .//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']
#view report button
view_report = .//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00']
#save button
save_button = .//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Button']
#csv button
csv_button = .//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu']/div[2]/a
#read path
read_path = E:\\Ashik\\wkspSelenium\\PropertyPractice\\src\\package1\\Month.txt
#write path
write_path = E:\\Ashik\\wkspSelenium\\PropertyPractice\\src\\package1\\Month.txt
```

Implementation.java:

```
package package1;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;

import package1.Fileaccessing;

public class Implementaion {

    public static  WebDriver driver;
    public  FileInputStream fis;
    public static String propertyfilepath="config.properties";
    public String browserName;

    //To get a key value from property file
    public String getProperty(String key) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
        fis=new FileInputStream(propertyfilepath);
        Properties prop=new Properties();
        prop.load(fis);
        return prop.getProperty(key);

    }
    public  static void initiate_webdriver() throws IOException
    {   
         // Changing default file downloading location  path using the FirefoxProfile.setpreference method.
          FirefoxProfile fprofile = new FirefoxProfile();   
          fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
          fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
          //file download path
          fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "E:\\"); //need to ask muthu
          //CSV format to download the data
          fprofile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv");
          //Automatically downloads the file without manual selection
          fprofile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force",false);
          fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertonComplete",false);
          fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone",false);
          //Assigning the created profile to Firefox driver

          WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(fprofile);
    }

    //To get a url in browser
        public  static void get_url(String link) throws InterruptedException
        {


            driver.get(link);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }

        //To select a value by visible text in a drop down


         public static void downloads_new_month(String xpath, String value)  throws InterruptedException
         {
              WebElement mSelectElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
              List<WebElement> optionsList = mSelectElement.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
              Fileaccessing fileAccessObject = new Fileaccessing();
              //Reading txt from the Month txt file
              String oldMonth = fileAccessObject.getTheOldMonthFromFile(propertyfilepath);
              System.out.println("The old month is: " + oldMonth);
              String newMonth =""; 

              for (int i = 2; i < optionsList.size(); i++) {

              WebElement element = optionsList.get(i);
              newMonth = element.getText();

              //Message that prints the new month
              System.out.println("The new month is:"+newMonth);


              /*Condition to check if the New month is equal to Old month, if it is not equal then proceeds
               * to download that particular month data or else breaks the loop
               */

              if (oldMonth.equals(newMonth)) {
              System.out.println("No new months are available to download");
              driver.close();
              break;
              }else if (i==2 & !(oldMonth.equals(newMonth))) {
              //else if (!(oldMonth.equals(newMonth))) {    
              element.click();
                //Click on View Report button
              driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
                //Wait time to load the selected month data
              Wait(20000);} 
              public static   saveButton(String xpath2 , String value2)   throws InterruptedException{
                //Click on File save button
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath2)).click();
                //wait time to load the File format options
              Wait(20000); } 
         public static void csvButton(String xpath3 , String value3) throws InterruptedException{
                //Click on csv format button
              driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath3)).click();
              Wait(10000);
                //Success message to indicate that the data is downloaded successfully in csv format
              System.out.println("New Month data downloaded in csv format:" + newMonth);
         }
              //Saves the new month txt to the file
         public static void save_new_month() {
              fileAccessObject.saveIntoAFile(newMonth, propertyfilepath);
              //closes the web page once the file is downloaded
              driver.close();
              break;
         }
        } }



         public static void Wait(int time){

            try {
                Thread.sleep(time);
                } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        } } 
}
```

I have successfully set up browser initialization and opening, now how to use it in download_new_month method, as there are 3 xpath's has to be clicked to download a report when condition is met. Please help.

Comment: Please post correct sources and explain what problems you've faced

Comment: these are the class files, see under download_new_method method there are 3 xpaths to be clicked and I have given 2 methods under that , they are savebutton and csvbutton, and constructors like xpath2 and xpath3.

Comment: When I'm dividing my code into different methods, driver, element type things asking me to recreate them , as they are unable to get in the scope. I've given static to all the methods.

Answer (score 0):

At the starting of the class used below one

```
  public static  WebDriver driver;
```

again in  public  static void initiate_webdriver()  method, using

```
 WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(fprofile);
```

looks not correct here, already driver is declared globally, so please use

```
 driver=new FirefoxDriver(fprofile);
```

in initiate_webdriver() method.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: that is ok, what about the 3 xpaths which is used in downloads_new_month method and other methods, how to make them not to show direct url's using property